# React - Login Variables cached in the browser

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm quite new to React and trying to learn it but have a strong background in backends (java/nodejs/php/...)

So first I wanted to create a login portal, basically 3 pages:
- The homepage which redirects you to login if you are not authenticated
- Login page
- Register page

The features are working (register/login/logout)
My problem is on the Homepage, if I first log in with user1, I will see Hello user1. If I log out and log in with user2, I will still see user1.

It seems that the variable is cached somehow by the browser.
F5 refresh actually updates the value ... :/

This is what I've done:

In my app, I have this route:

```
<Provider store={store}>
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/register" name="Register" component={Register} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/" name="Home" component={Layout} />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </Provider>
```

The provider configureStore is doing :

```
store.dispatch(requestUserInfo());
```

And this requestUserInfo() is something I created in the following class
I get the token, decode it with jwt and render some user info:

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'

export const REQUEST_USER = "REQUEST_USER";
export const USER_INFO = "USER_INFO";

export function requestUserInfo() {
if(localStorage.usertoken){
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.usertoken)
  let usertest = {
    "username": decoded.first_name + " " + decoded.last_name,
    "picture": "assets/img/avatars/test.png",
    "activity": 1
  } 

  return dispatch => {

      dispatch({
        type: USER_INFO,
        payload: usertest
      });

  };
} else {
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_INFO,
        payload: {"username": "","picture": "","activity": 0}
      });
  };
}
}

export default function isLogged() {
let status = false

if(localStorage.usertoken){
  try{
    if(jwt_decode(localStorage.usertoken)){
      status = true;
    }
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }

}

return status
}
```

When doing the logout, I remove the token by doing :
localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')

**Edit: When trying to do a 1st login in a private tab, nothing is shown, the variables are empty. Looks like my variables are set after the rendering maybe?**

**Edit2: I put everything on github so it might be easier to debug: https://github.com/senechalm/learning-reactjs**

Does anyone have any idea/suggestion on how to fix this issue/bug?

Comment: Where are you storing your JWT? When you logout, you should clear the JWT.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, it's in the browser local storage, when I logout I already do localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')

Comment: What does `const decoded = jwt_decode(token)` refers to in your code? This is not explicit. If you keep this on memory, updating localStorage won't work. Your problem might be that you get the token by reference and not evaluate it every single time.

Comment: the token is retrieved from the local storage, in the top of the the class: export const token = localStorage.usertoken;

Comment: @MorganSenechal can you share more code of the class?

Comment: @InacioSchweller I added the full content of the UserArction.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in the repo some issues that we can fix in 3 steps:

1. lets redo  `requestUserInfo()` so we return action, but not calling dispatch:

```
export function requestUserInfo() {
    if(sessionStorage.usertoken){
      const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.usertoken)
       let usertest = {
        "username": decoded.first_name + " " + decoded.last_name,
        "picture": "assets/img/avatars/sunny.png",
        "activity": 12
      } 
      return {
            type: USER_INFO,
            payload: usertest
          };        
    } else {      
      return {
            type: USER_INFO,
            payload: {username: "",picture: "",activity: 0}
          };    
    }
}
```

2. in Home.js with state we map dispatch:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => state.user;

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    requestUserInfo: ()=> dispatch(requestUserInfo()) 
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

3. we should use `componentDidMount` now as `componentWillMount` marked UNSAFE, so remove it and add:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("before"+this.props.username)
    this.props.requestUserInfo();
    console.log("after"+this.props.username)
}
```

Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, Thanks, this fixed my issue and now I understand what I did wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have incorrect values in redux. If you are not using redux dev tools - please install it and check your values in reducer after logout and second login.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue happens becase you don't clear your `localStorage.usertoken` after the logout.

Run `removeItem` from localStorage on logout's dispatch:

```
localStorage.removeItem("usertoken")
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that but I already do localStorage.removeItem('usertoken') when logout

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when creating a const for `token`, you should always be getting it from localStorage and not from reference, e.g.

```
export function requestUserInfo() {
if(localStorage.usertoken){
  //If you get it from reference, token will be the past user's information and not the 
  //new one.
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.usertoken)
  let usertest = {
    "username": decoded.first_name + " " + decoded.last_name,
    "picture": "test",
    "activity": 1
  } 
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_INFO,
        payload: usertest
      });
  };
} else {
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_INFO,
        payload: {"username": "","picture": "","activity": 0}
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: I changed it as you mention but still have the same issue. (I first used a variable "token" because I wanted to read from the storage once instead of multiple times)